# Value check directly in the query using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

I've the following table:

**friends**:

```
id | user1 | user2   | status
1  | Jorge | Alisson | 3
2  | Lucas | Jorge   | 3
```

And to do a `SELECT`, I do (the variable `$userLogged` refers to the user logged in at the time):

```
SELECT user1, user2, status
FROM friends
WHERE user1 = '$userLogged' OR user2 = '$userLogged'
```

So, in PHP:

```
foreach($query as $q) {
    if($q["user1"] == $userLogged) {
        $userFriend = $q["user2"];
    } else {
        $userFriend = $q["user1"];
    }
}
```

Suppose the `$userLogged` is Jorge. I want to get the friend (`$userFriend`), that is, which is not `$userLogged` (Alisson and Lucas, in case). Currently I do this check in the manner shown above, with PHP. How can I do this directly in the query, thus saving this check in PHP? For ex.: `SELECT user1 AND user2 <> '$userLogged' AS userFriend`...

Comment: Is there a user table? I'd have friends have userid, friendid. Then you could easily do a join for all of `Jorge`s friends. This way you will have to do a self join and if you have users with the same name theres no way to distinguish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN user1 = '$userLogged' THEN user2
ELSE user1 END AS userFriend
FROM friends
WHERE user1 = '$userLogged' OR user2 = '$userLogged'
```

Comment: It worked! But, how can I use the `userFriend` in a `ON` clause? Like: `friends INNER JOIN users ON userFriend = user`, because I've: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'userFriend' in 'on clause'`

Comment: Just put the CASE statement in the ON statement. 

SELECT
...
FROM friends INNER JOIN Blah ON CASE WHEN user1 = '$userLogged' THEN user2
ELSE user1 END = whatever
WHERE user1 = '$userLogged' OR user2 = '$userLogged'

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you have an index on `friends(user1, user2, status)` and `friends(user2, user1, status)`, then the fastest way is:

```
SELECT user2 as `user`, status
FROM friends
WHERE user1 = '$userLogged' 
UNION ALL
SELECT user1, status
FROM friends
WHERE user2 = '$userLogged';
```

The index can be used for both subqueries, so this should be very fast.